# REST : GET but with a requestBody

Tags: rest, http, http-get

I'm writing an Endpoint who will extract data. My issue is, the client request need to pass a list of (very complex) object to my enpoint, along other complexe datas.

The whole thing look to complexe to pass by parameters.
**Should I still use a GET? can I do it with a requestBody? Or can I do a POST with a response body ?
My endpoint still need to respect REST**

the data I need to pass:
{id :"anUuid",
comment : "some very long text sometime more than 1000 char",
dataComputedByOtherServer:[{id:"anUuid",stuff:{"a lot of other stuff"}}]

}

the response body:
{
//allong with the usual REST response http code and other error message
payload:{
moreComplexData:[{id:"anUuid",stuff:{"a lot of other stuff"}}]
}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no body payload with an HTTP GET - you'll need to use POST (or PUT) to send this as needed.

Comment: So I will need a big responsebody to this post. will it still respect REST?

Comment: In regards to [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) a payload received via `GET` has no defined semantics. This is something different than completely rejecting it. The RFC also contains a warning that one SHOULD NOT send a payload in case you deal with generic HTTP clients/servers as they might reject such a request though. For internal communication there is nothing wrong with such requests, I would avoid it, for interoperability reasons, when dealing with external peers though

Comment: @sab In regards to REST, how is the client taught by the server to send the data? Usually the server will include any information the client will need to make the next request. Just think of the Web where a server sends a form representation (HTML) where the affordance of each of the form elements will tell the client what it can do with the provided data (i.e. select one or multiple options, enter or edit some freetext, ..., push a submit button). Such forms usually also contain the target endpoint, the representation to marshal the data to as well as the HTTP operation to use

Comment: @sab just reuse this concept used for HTML forms (which use `POST` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if not specified otherwise). While there are some JSON based form-approaches, such as hal-forms, Siren, ... they might not yet be final or have gained widespread usage so far. In regards to using `POST`  vs. `GET`, `POST` is an all-purpose operation that should be used in case no other method fits the task at hand, due to limitations or violated semantics.

Answer (score 1):

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics -- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1

So GET is out of bounds.

In the long term, the method want may eventually be SEARCH; see https://github.com/httpwg/http-extensions/issues/943

> While POST with the header defined in #942 would help, POST is still an unsafe method that poorly reflects the safe, idempotent semantics of search-like operations. I therefore argue that a a SEARCH method is needed to have a safe, idempotent method with explicit caching support, in opposition to POST which explicitly is not cacheable.

But we aren't there as of 2019: the semantics of SEARCH are still defined by the [WebDAV specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5323), where they don't quite mean what you want.